# Installing packages in pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, package

I'm kinda new to programming, and this is one of my first projects, a data science project.
I am using PyCharm and I need to install numpy and pandas (and probably many others later).
But I can't manage to download any package.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried different versions of numpy and pandas, tried with the terminal, and tried to use a Virtualenv and a Conda environment.
If you have any suggestion I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: Use PyCharm itself to download packages into the interpreter you are using for your project.

Comment: It did not work, or maybe I did it wrong (which is highly possible).

Comment: I had the same issue when I updated pip. I rolled back to a previous version but it can also be a bug from pycharm. Try to update it to the bran new version (2020.2.5)

Comment: please always post your code/commands and errors in textual form with code formatting (select+ curly brackets in editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discuss in comments : Pycharm 2020.2.4 is bugged with pip install, update to 2020.2.5 (and probably next versions in the future) resolve the issue.